# laravel eloquent not returning any data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

### agency.php

```
class agency extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'agency';

    public function organizations()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\model\organization');
    }
}
```

---

### agencyController.php

```
$agency = \App\model\agency::with('organizations')->get();
```

### agency.blade.php

```
@foreach($agency as $agency)
<tr>
  <th>{{$agency['id']}}</th>
  <th>{{$agency['agency_name']}}</th>
  <th>{{$agency['linked_organization_id']}}</th>
  <th>{{$agency['created_at']}}</th>
  <th>{{$agency['updated_at']}}</th>
  <th>{{$agency->organizations->organization_name}}</th>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

### Error

Trying to get property of non-object

Why {{$agency->organizations->organization_name}} does not return data???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many errors at your code:

**1st:** Why the relationship name is `organization>s<` (plural) if it 
refers to a single organization?

It's really a single organization, or you confused typing your relationship?

**2nd:** This is probably the cause of your problem:

`@foreach($agency as $agency)`

You are using the same variable name for your array and item.

By doing this, on first **foreach** iteration, you will have a model, nice. But you have replaced the "foreached" array by an model.

Now in subsequent iterations, the foreach will iterate over the attributes of your model.

That the reason why `$agency->organizations` will give an error!

**3rd: (new)** Your organizations relationship is **wrong**!

```
public function organizations()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\model\organization');
}
```

Using this way, Laravel presumes that your foreign key is `organizations_id`. But on your code, I've seen that your foreign key is `linked_organization_id`. So you have to specify the Foreign Key name!

```
public function organizations()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\model\organization', 'linked_organization_id');
}
```

## My advise:

1. **Array**/**Collection** variables **SHOULD** be named as **plural**
2. **Model** and other values variables **SHOULD** be named as **singular**.

This will prevent you from making that mistake again.

### Another suggestion:

Laravel follows [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) (autoload) and [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) (coding-style) standards.

This give you many orientations how you should write your code.

I've seen that your classes names are using `lowerCamelCase`, but PSR-2 uses `upperCamelCase` as default.

Comment: ok, from next time i'll keep it in mind. but when I execute {{$agency}}, it showing {"id":2,"agency_name":"test_agency_2","linked_organization_id":2,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"organization":null}, why organization is null??

Comment: @DipankarNaskar take a look at the **3rd** (new) error at my answer! Your relationship declaration is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@foreach($agencies as $agency)
<tr>
  <th>{{$agency['id']}}</th>
  <th>{{$agency['agency_name']}}</th>
  <th>{{$agency['linked_organization_id']}}</th>
  <th>{{$agency['created_at']}}</th>
  <th>{{$agency['updated_at']}}</th>
  <th>{{$agency->organizations()->organization_name}}</th>
</tr>
@endforeach
```